# GEKKO APOPT does not solve a simple problem

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to solve a production problem using the GEKKO APOPT integer optimizer. I have already greatly simplified the conditions, but the solver cannot cope with it even after 10,000 iterations. If I leave 3-4 constraints, it needs almost 4000 iterations. Please tell me any ideas for setting up. The code and content of the source file are below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO


BD = pd.read_csv('BD2222.csv', sep = ';')

PZ = pd.DataFrame()
PZ['protuct'] = ['protuct '+str(i + 1) for i in range(10)]
PZ['quantity'] = 100
PZ['Term'] = 3

model = GEKKO(remote=False)
model.options.DIAGLEVEL = 2


vars = []
for i in BD.index:
    vars.append(model.Var(name = 'Var_{0}'.format(i), integer = True, lb = 0, ub = 8)) 
   
vars = pd.Series(vars)
#vars[0].lower = 1
for i in range(7):
    vars[i].value = 1
    
    
nom = BD[['Day', 'Boiler number']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
Temp_ind = nom.apply(lambda x, BD: BD[(BD['Day'] == x['Day']) & (BD['Boiler number'] == x['Boiler number'])].index.values.tolist(), axis = 1, args = [BD])
equ = []
for i in nom.index:
    equ.append(vars[Temp_ind[i]].sum() <= 8)
    

ind = PZ.apply(lambda x, BD: BD[(BD['protuct'] == x['protuct']) & (x['Term'] >= BD['Day'])].index.values.tolist(), axis = 1, args = [BD])
vih = BD['quantity']

for i in PZ.index:
    equ.append((vars[ind[i]] * vih[ind[i]]).sum() > PZ.loc[i, 'quantity'])


model.Equations(equ)


model.Minimize(model.sum((vars * BD['Cost']).tolist()))


model.options.SOLVER=1
model.solve(disp=True, debug = True)
```

Source data BD2222.csv

```
protuct;Boiler number;quantity;Day;Cost
protuct 1;1;400;0;18046
protuct 2;1;400;0;18763
protuct 3;1;400;0;20219
protuct 4;1;400;0;19286
protuct 5;1;400;0;19877
protuct 6;1;400;0;18878
protuct 7;1;400;0;19144
protuct 8;1;400;0;18777
protuct 9;1;400;0;19325
protuct 10;1;400;0;19695
protuct 1;2;800;0;36083
protuct 2;2;800;0;37516
protuct 3;2;800;0;40429
protuct 4;2;800;0;38562
protuct 5;2;800;0;39744
protuct 6;2;800;0;37747
protuct 7;2;800;0;38279
protuct 8;2;800;0;37544
protuct 9;2;800;0;38640
protuct 10;2;800;0;39381
protuct 1;1;200;0;9028
protuct 2;1;200;0;9386
protuct 3;1;200;0;10114
protuct 4;1;200;0;9648
protuct 5;1;200;0;9943
protuct 6;1;200;0;9444
protuct 7;1;200;0;9577
protuct 8;1;200;0;9393
protuct 9;1;200;0;9667
protuct 10;1;200;0;9852
protuct 1;2;200;0;9028
protuct 2;2;200;0;9386
protuct 3;2;200;0;10114
protuct 4;2;200;0;9648
protuct 5;2;200;0;9943
protuct 6;2;200;0;9444
protuct 7;2;200;0;9577
protuct 8;2;200;0;9393
protuct 9;2;200;0;9667
protuct 10;2;200;0;9852
protuct 1;2;400;0;18046
protuct 2;2;400;0;18763
protuct 3;2;400;0;20219
protuct 4;2;400;0;19286
protuct 5;2;400;0;19877
protuct 6;2;400;0;18878
protuct 7;2;400;0;19144
protuct 8;2;400;0;18777
protuct 9;2;400;0;19325
protuct 10;2;400;0;19695
protuct 1;1;400;1;18047
protuct 2;1;400;1;18764
protuct 3;1;400;1;20220
protuct 4;1;400;1;19287
protuct 5;1;400;1;19878
protuct 6;1;400;1;18879
protuct 7;1;400;1;19145
protuct 8;1;400;1;18778
protuct 9;1;400;1;19326
protuct 10;1;400;1;19696
protuct 1;2;800;1;36084
protuct 2;2;800;1;37517
protuct 3;2;800;1;40430
protuct 4;2;800;1;38563
protuct 5;2;800;1;39745
protuct 6;2;800;1;37748
protuct 7;2;800;1;38280
protuct 8;2;800;1;37545
protuct 9;2;800;1;38641
protuct 10;2;800;1;39382
protuct 1;1;200;1;9029
protuct 2;1;200;1;9387
protuct 3;1;200;1;10115
protuct 4;1;200;1;9649
protuct 5;1;200;1;9944
protuct 6;1;200;1;9445
protuct 7;1;200;1;9578
protuct 8;1;200;1;9394
protuct 9;1;200;1;9668
protuct 10;1;200;1;9853
protuct 1;2;200;1;9029
protuct 2;2;200;1;9387
protuct 3;2;200;1;10115
protuct 4;2;200;1;9649
protuct 5;2;200;1;9944
protuct 6;2;200;1;9445
protuct 7;2;200;1;9578
protuct 8;2;200;1;9394
protuct 9;2;200;1;9668
protuct 10;2;200;1;9853
protuct 1;2;400;1;18047
protuct 2;2;400;1;18764
protuct 3;2;400;1;20220
protuct 4;2;400;1;19287
protuct 5;2;400;1;19878
protuct 6;2;400;1;18879
protuct 7;2;400;1;19145
protuct 8;2;400;1;18778
protuct 9;2;400;1;19326
protuct 10;2;400;1;19696
protuct 1;1;400;2;18048
protuct 2;1;400;2;18765
protuct 3;1;400;2;20221
protuct 4;1;400;2;19288
protuct 5;1;400;2;19879
protuct 6;1;400;2;18880
protuct 7;1;400;2;19146
protuct 8;1;400;2;18779
protuct 9;1;400;2;19327
protuct 10;1;400;2;19697
protuct 1;2;800;2;36085
protuct 2;2;800;2;37518
protuct 3;2;800;2;40431
protuct 4;2;800;2;38564
protuct 5;2;800;2;39746
protuct 6;2;800;2;37749
protuct 7;2;800;2;38281
protuct 8;2;800;2;37546
protuct 9;2;800;2;38642
protuct 10;2;800;2;39383
protuct 1;1;200;2;9030
protuct 2;1;200;2;9388
protuct 3;1;200;2;10116
protuct 4;1;200;2;9650
protuct 5;1;200;2;9945
protuct 6;1;200;2;9446
protuct 7;1;200;2;9579
protuct 8;1;200;2;9395
protuct 9;1;200;2;9669
protuct 10;1;200;2;9854
protuct 1;2;200;2;9030
protuct 2;2;200;2;9388
protuct 3;2;200;2;10116
protuct 4;2;200;2;9650
protuct 5;2;200;2;9945
protuct 6;2;200;2;9446
protuct 7;2;200;2;9579
protuct 8;2;200;2;9395
protuct 9;2;200;2;9669
protuct 10;2;200;2;9854
protuct 1;2;400;2;18048
protuct 2;2;400;2;18765
protuct 3;2;400;2;20221
protuct 4;2;400;2;19288
protuct 5;2;400;2;19879
protuct 6;2;400;2;18880
protuct 7;2;400;2;19146
protuct 8;2;400;2;18779
protuct 9;2;400;2;19327
protuct 10;2;400;2;19697
protuct 1;1;400;3;18049
protuct 2;1;400;3;18766
protuct 3;1;400;3;20222
protuct 4;1;400;3;19289
protuct 5;1;400;3;19880
protuct 6;1;400;3;18881
protuct 7;1;400;3;19147
protuct 8;1;400;3;18780
protuct 9;1;400;3;19328
protuct 10;1;400;3;19698
protuct 1;2;800;3;36086
protuct 2;2;800;3;37519
protuct 3;2;800;3;40432
protuct 4;2;800;3;38565
protuct 5;2;800;3;39747
protuct 6;2;800;3;37750
protuct 7;2;800;3;38282
protuct 8;2;800;3;37547
protuct 9;2;800;3;38643
protuct 10;2;800;3;39384
protuct 1;1;200;3;9031
protuct 2;1;200;3;9389
protuct 3;1;200;3;10117
protuct 4;1;200;3;9651
protuct 5;1;200;3;9946
protuct 6;1;200;3;9447
protuct 7;1;200;3;9580
protuct 8;1;200;3;9396
protuct 9;1;200;3;9670
protuct 10;1;200;3;9855
protuct 1;2;200;3;9031
protuct 2;2;200;3;9389
protuct 3;2;200;3;10117
protuct 4;2;200;3;9651
protuct 5;2;200;3;9946
protuct 6;2;200;3;9447
protuct 7;2;200;3;9580
protuct 8;2;200;3;9396
protuct 9;2;200;3;9670
protuct 10;2;200;3;9855
protuct 1;2;400;3;18049
protuct 2;2;400;3;18766
protuct 3;2;400;3;20222
protuct 4;2;400;3;19289
protuct 5;2;400;3;19880
protuct 6;2;400;3;18881
protuct 7;2;400;3;19147
protuct 8;2;400;3;18780
protuct 9;2;400;3;19328
protuct 10;2;400;3;19698
```

I tried to change the settings
and analyzed the returned data of the solver
I changed the source data
and tried to add restrictions in turn
Solved the problem in IPOPT before solving in APOPT

Answer (score 0):

Try using [solver option](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) `minlp_branch_method 1` to find an integer solution earlier. This helps to prune off other potential solutions and return an integer solution quicker.

```py
model.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-3',\
                        'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                        'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                        'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
```

Here is a complete script:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
BD = pd.read_csv('BD2222.csv', sep = ';')
PZ = pd.DataFrame()
PZ['protuct'] = ['protuct '+str(i + 1) for i in range(10)]
PZ['quantity'] = 100
PZ['Term'] = 3
model = GEKKO(remote=True)
model.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
vars = []
for i in BD.index:
    vars.append(model.Var(name = 'Var_{0}'.format(i), integer = True, lb = 0, ub = 8)) 
vars = pd.Series(vars)
#vars[0].lower = 1
for i in range(7):
    vars[i].value = 1
nom = BD[['Day', 'Boiler number']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True)
Temp_ind = nom.apply(lambda x, BD: BD[(BD['Day'] == x['Day']) & (BD['Boiler number'] == x['Boiler number'])].index.values.tolist(), axis = 1, args = [BD])
equ = []
for i in nom.index:
    equ.append(vars[Temp_ind[i]].sum() <= 8)
ind = PZ.apply(lambda x, BD: BD[(BD['protuct'] == x['protuct']) & (x['Term'] >= BD['Day'])].index.values.tolist(), axis = 1, args = [BD])
vih = BD['quantity']
for i in PZ.index:
    equ.append((vars[ind[i]] * vih[ind[i]]).sum() > PZ.loc[i, 'quantity'])
model.Equations(equ)
for x in (vars * BD['Cost']).tolist():
    model.Minimize(x)
model.options.SOLVER=1
#model.open_folder()
model.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-3',\
                        'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                        'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                        'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
model.solve(disp=True, debug = True)
```

It solves in about 1.4 sec.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    1.41649999999936      sec
 Objective      :    96076.0000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

You may want to increase `minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500` to a higher value to continue searching for a solution, even when an integer solution is found within the first 500 iterations. Setting this value to 10000 lowers the objective function from 96076 to 96072. You can continue iterating, but the incremental improvement may not be that much. The `gap_tol` controls the termination criterion as well. Mixed Integer problems can take a long time to solve if the tolerance is small.